# Applying temporal antialiasing?

Tags: animation, video, ffmpeg

Can anyone recommend a workflow or an existing solution that lets me apply temporal antialiasing to an animation? I'm observing temporal artifacts when animating rendered graphics -- fast moving objects create ghosting artifacts.

[image]

I prototyped [something](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/255673/217) in Mathematica that does the job, but it's quite slow, wondering if there's a faster open source solution. Example below blends 45 images per frame

[image]